# How do I use python session variables in gcloud appengine

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, gcloud, session-variables

I need global variables to use in a Flask Web app.  Currently, I am trying to use session variables and they work just fine on the local development machine.  However, when I upload the code to gcloud appengine, I find that the value of the session variable does not persist.  Here is my code regarding the session variable.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app.wsgi_app = wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app, use_deferred=True)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = Settings.secretKey
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
```

and the @before_request decorator,

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if not session.get('user_id_string'):
        session['user_id_string'] = ""
    if not session.get('user_role_string'):
        session['user_role_string'] = ""
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        session['logged_in'] = False
```

However, the value of the session variables do not last and the @before_request function sometimes resets values instead of persisting them.  How do I set up the session (or any other variable) so that their value persists throughout the user session please?

Comment: Looks like you're using the extension ```Flask-Session``` which means you have to initialize it as ```Session(app)```. Because you can't write to Filesystem  in GAE standard, you can't even use ```SESSION_TYPE = filesystem```. Since you want this data per user, why are you storing them as different session variables? Wouldn't it be better to simply have something like ```session["user"] =  {"user_id_string" :<ABC>, "user_role_string": <ABC>} and then you only check if session["user"] exists?

Answer (score 1):

You've set up sessions to use the file system:

```
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
```

App Engine doesn't let you write to disk.  You should use cookies for storing the session.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  So I use the default for SESSION_TYPE.  Is there anything else I need to do please?

Comment: For example, do I need to write the session variables onto the cookie and read the cookie to get at the variables?  Sorry but I am a noob where sessions are concerned.

Comment: Just to add, I've tried without the app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem' statement and the variables still don't work consistently.

Comment: Storing session data in variables is not a good idea, your browser could connect with any App Engine back-end and the session data would not be available. Redis or Storage (e.g Firestore) is a better idea

Comment: @rossco, how about mongo please?

Comment: Yes you could use mongo or any DB, obviously read time varies a lot between all the options. I mentioned Redis as I know it is lightning fast

Comment: Firestore is mentioned as a solution but there isn't a coding example which will lead to another rabbit hole of research. Could someone provide a solution with Firestore working code?